# I have read (programming in c 3rd edition book). I can't understand, what they have mentioned. Could anyone please explain the following paragraph?

Tags: c

When a program terminates simply by executing the last statement in main, its exit
status is undefined. If another program needs to use this exit status, you mustn’t let this
happen. In such a case, make certain that you exit or return from main with a defined
exit status.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: That is incorrect. If `main` does not `return` a value, the compiler assumes it returns 0. It's true for all *other* functions.

Comment: What C standard version is covered by that book? Implicit `return 0;` for `main` was already part of C99. If that book uses an even older version, you should get rid of it. There were lots of improvements in C99.

Answer (score 3):

What is says is that if you don't have a `return` statement from the `main` function, the returned value is indeterminate (just like missing a `return` statement from another function declared to return a value).

***However*** this is no longer true. Since the C99 standard if there's no explicit `return` statement in the `main` function, the compiler will add an implicit `return 0;` at the end.